# store more than one value with same para name of URL into array

Tags: php

```
min=112&max=131&sid=1&sid=46&sid=6
```

The above is the code snippet of URL. my question is how store all sid value into **$idArr** in PHP and output will be as below.
    Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 46
        [2] => 6
    )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to rename `sid` to `sid[]` and `$_GET['sid']` will be an array:

- http://codepad.org/rmfhwGA6

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work, because you can't use the same GET parameter more than once. If you use it more than once, it will overwrite the previous value.

You could create your own separator char.

URL:

```
sids=1*2*3*4*5
```

Parsing:

```
<?php
$sidArray = explode('*', $_GET['sids']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jsonencode on an array and send the values using jquery get and jsondecode on the receiving end, i would also recoment urlencode and urldecode functions